# Fixing errors installing QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, ubuntu

I’m trying to install the latest QGIS stable version 3.26.x on my ubuntu 20.04 system. I’m following [these instructions at qgis.org,](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) starting at “Here you will simply install the latest stable QGIS“.

All is well until the actual QGIS installation step:

```
$ sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: libexiv2-27 (>= 0.27.3) but 0.27.2-8ubuntu2.7 is to be installed
        Depends: libgdal28 (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
        Depends: libproj19 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-3d3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-gui3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
        Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.26.3+16bullseye) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.26.3+16bullseye) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.26.3+16bullseye) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: grass785 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libgdal28 (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libqgis-app3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-core3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-gui3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.26.3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Lots of information there, but it's not clear to me how to fix the problem.

What is wrong?

Comment: please add the details of all the qgis entries in your apt sources, the other thing to try is removing your existing qgis and gdal installs before trying to install

Comment: This ubuntu machine is also used to develop an unrelated application that uses gdal and proj libraries, and I can't afford to break that - maybe it's better that I not try install QGIS here...

Comment: shouldn't be a problem unless the other app requires fixed versions that are different to qgis

Comment: Well I've got a different laptop with freshly installed ubuntu 20.04 - never installed qgis, gdal, proj on this laptop - and get almost the exact same errors. I'm following instructions at https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. What is wrong here?  @IanTurton what do you mean "add the details of all the qgis entries in your apt sources"? Sorry, how do I provide that information? Thanks!

Comment: When I run `grep -i qgis **/*.sources **/*.list *.list` in `/etc/apt`  I see `sources.list.d/qgis.sources:URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
sources.list.d/qgis.sources:Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
sources.list:#deb [arch=amd64] http://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
sources.list:#deb [arch=amd64] http://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main` what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I blundered by simply copy-and-pasting the QGIS repo example shown [in the instructions,](https://Types:%20deb%20deb-src%20URIs:%20https://qgis.org/debian%20Suites:%20bullseye%20Architectures:%20amd64%20Components:%20main%20Signed-By:%20/etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg) which specifies "Suites: bullseye". I am using ubuntu 20.04, so the entry should be "Suites: focal". Now the install works. Thank you for our help @Ian Turton!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the issue for me too.